# multiply value in 2 dropdownlists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the best part of 2 days trying to figure out how to "times 2 dropdownlists" with each other and show it in a label...

like in math when u mutiple 2 numbers..

plzz help me...

all suggestions are welcome

```
Protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int amount1 = int.parse(DropDownList1.selectedValue.ToString());
     int amount2 = int.parse(DropDownList1.selectedValue.ToString());

     Label.Text = amount1 * amount2;
}
```

i get an error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Int' to 'string

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
Label.Text = (amount1 * amount2).ToString();
```

as you cannot assign integer result to string Label.Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way

```
int val = amount1 * amount2;
Label.Text = val.ToString();
```

`Label.Text` expects String and you were trying to assign integer to it.